# What would happen if you get 0 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

The privilege for 1 reputation is posting. But if you have 0 reputation, wouldn't you be unable to post? If so, how would you fix that?

Comment: you would have been suspended otherwise the floor is 1

Comment: oh. so I will have 1 reputation always unless im suspended

Comment: Actually, it means your enemy hacked SE, as they are sure 0 is too unnatural even for list-numbers, let alone reputation...

Comment: 1 is the lowest reputation users can have, despite how many down-votes such a users receives.

Comment: @Plutonix that is wrong.  No one, even suspended users, can have less than 1

Comment: If your reputation is zero check the date; it's probably April 1st.

Comment: I'm afraid of clicking on your username :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

0 reputation does not exist.  It is impossible for anyone, no matter how bad their questions are to get less than 1 rep.

So if you have 0 rep, it means you have either broken the site or are on a bad phishing site.

Comment: Its even in the help center: [All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: point taken, 9 downvotes and I still have 1 rep

Comment: @php.exe Votes on meta don't affect your reputation

Comment: If you wake up in the morning and find that you have zero rep, you are going to have a very bad day.